# Why RemoteView.setColorStateList() not accessible?

Tags: android, remoteview, android-remoteview

My use-case is to set background for a view inside RemoteView layout.

```
remoteViews.setInt(R.id.infoRightTitle, "setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.icon)
remoteViews.setColorStateList(R.id.infoRightTitle, "setBackgroundTintList", ContextCompat.getColorStateList(appContext,R.color.red))
```

But i was surprised to find that setColorStateList was not available and shows a compilation error.

> Unresolved reference: setColorStateList

### RemoteViews.java

```
/**
 * Call a method taking one int on a view in the layout for this RemoteViews.
 *
 * @param viewId The id of the view on which to call the method.
 * @param methodName The name of the method to call.
 * @param value The value to pass to the method.
 */
public void setInt(int viewId, String methodName, int value) {
    addAction(new ReflectionAction(viewId, methodName, ReflectionAction.INT, value));
}

/**
 * Call a method taking one ColorStateList on a view in the layout for this RemoteViews.
 *
 * @param viewId The id of the view on which to call the method.
 * @param methodName The name of the method to call.
 * @param value The value to pass to the method.
 *
 * @hide
 */
public void setColorStateList(int viewId, String methodName, ColorStateList value) {
    addAction(new ReflectionAction(viewId, methodName, ReflectionAction.COLOR_STATE_LIST,
            value));
}
```

I can see an annotation @hide in the code but no other comments while the method is public.
The code i have shared is simplified version to give a gist of the issue.

Need help to find the solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

As of API 31, [setColorStateList](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews#setColorStateList(int,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.res.ColorStateList,%20android.content.res.ColorStateList)) is supported on `RemoteViews`.